# Twitter Bootstrap CSS not loading?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to web development and am trying to make a site using Bootstrap v3.20
This is my project structure

```
bootstrap/
|---index.html
├── css/
│   ├── bootstrap.css
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   ├── bootstrap-theme.css
│   ├── jumbotron-narrow.css
│   ├── styles.css             //blank
│   └── bootstrap-theme.min.css
├── js/
│   ├── bootstrap.js
│   ├── jquery-1.10.2.js
│   └── bootstrap.min.js
└── fonts/
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
    ├── glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
    └── glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
```

**index.html**
this is fromm the bootstrap website since I'm testing out using the framework

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Narrow Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>  
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron-narrow.css" rel="stylesheet"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>﻿
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="text-muted">Project name</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Jumbotron heading</h1>
        <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">Sign up today</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="row marketing">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h4>Subheading</h4>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

          <h4>Subheading</h4>
          <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

          <h4>Subheading</h4>
          <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <h4>Subheading</h4>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum.</p>

          <h4>Subheading</h4>
          <p>Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>

          <h4>Subheading</h4>
          <p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**and index.html when trying to launch in Chrome**
[image: hmmm]

I am still very new to web dev, as I said, so I'm sure it is obvious. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Look into absolute vs relative paths - looks like that's your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify on the comment: the CSS tag pointed toward an absolute URL:

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But the CSS file was absolutely located at `/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`. Absolute URLs should generally be avoided, unless you're 100% sure that the reference will live there regardless of what position your site lives.

The relative URL of:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

will work.

A site can live at the web root, or up a level or more, depending on how you set up your server. You'll often see this in development environments where your local development may be at a different level than your production environment - in that situation, a relative link will work either way, but an absolute link will be broken in one or the other.

Relative location generally works best when your resource lives relative to your page, like with static HTML files. If you're using a framework like ASP.NET, especially when working with partial views or user controls, you can define a link relative to your application instead of relative to the page, and let it do the work.